# The right way to go about creating a WordPress site from a static site which has WordPress installs in its subdirectory

Tags: directory, installation

I've created a static site for a business code in plain HTML and CSS. Along the way, I've added in two WordPress installs in subdirectories, one being a blog page and another being an eCommerce site.

Now that the website has begun to grow, the client suggested making the main static site part of WordPress. Now I am most definitely not a WordPress expert and am not sure what could potentially happen so please bear with me.

I am a bit wary of installing WordPress to the root directory of the site, to replace the main site, as I fear it may break the blog and eCommerce stores since they're installed in subdirectories.

What would be the best way to go about doing this and what steps/precautions should I take.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends what is suitable for you, as you said :

> I've added in two WordPress installs in subdirectories, one being a
>   blog page and another being an eCommerce site

and now you want to make your static site dynamic with WordPress, you have options, either you can merge all your sites in one WordPress installation OR install a new WordPress for your main site.

i would suggest, you should merge all your sites in one **IF they both are on same domain**, you can find any suitable theme similar to your design or you can also convert your static site in WordPress theme.

Comment: How would I merge all the sites into one installation?

Comment: first tell me why you installed two separate wordpress? are both sites on different domains? or you have only one domain for both (your blog and ecommerce)?

Comment: I have one domain for both. So one is at www.example.com/blog and the other is at www.example.com/store . I am still very new to WordPress so please forgive me.

Comment: thats what i want to know!, i would suggest you should merge all in one WordPress installation, install a new WordPress & find any suitable theme (if you want to change your site design), then shift all your content to the new WordPress, it will be easier for you to manage all from one dashboard, instead of different for each site.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this without affecting the other installs?

Comment: do it on your local machine first, you should complete it at your local machine then upload your full new web once its totally complete, your existing site will remain live until you are done with your new one, you should ask for senior's help around you, if you are still not sure what to do.

Answer (score -1):

I run several servers that each run multiple instances of wordpress.  Usually the main site is at the root of the public_html folder so it would look like this:

wp-admin/

wp-content/

wp-includes/

wp-config.php

.htaccess

(all other wordpressfiles)

site2.com (with its own wordpress inside)

site3.com (with its own wordpress inside)

**Everything runs fine and very smoothly.**

Just make sure of 2 things.  backup your old main site first before updating to wordpress and 2ndly if you use a backup tool/plugin for the new wordpress site you'll need to make an exclusion within it to make sure that you don't backup the other sites within the main.